# Как реализовать систему подписок и подписчиков в БД через SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

На данный момент у меня есть следующий код:
**Код модели** ( /data/.__all_models.py )

```py
followers = sqlalchemy.Table(
    'followers',
    SqlAlchemyBase.metadata,
    sqlalchemy.Column("author_id", sqlalchemy.Integer, sqlalchemy.ForeignKey("users.id")),
    sqlalchemy.Column("follower_id", sqlalchemy.Integer, sqlalchemy.ForeignKey("users.id")),
)


class User(SqlAlchemyBase):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True, 
                           autoincrement=True)
    name = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String, nullable=True)
    followers = sqlalchemy.orm.relation(
        "User",
        secondary="followers",
        backref="following"
    )
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<User id: {self.id}, name: {self.name}>"
```

**Код заполнения БД** ( /main.py )

```py
from data.db_session import global_init, create_session
from data.__all_models import User

global_init("db/data_base.db")  # Просто инициализация БД. Если уже создана, то подключаемся. 
                                # Иначе, создается БД data_base.db. К ней же и подключаемся
session = create_session()

user1 = User(name="user1")
session.add(user1)
user2 = User(name="user2")
session.add(user2)

user1.followers.append(user2)
session.commit()
print(user1.followers)
```

И при выполнении кода в **main.py** вылезает следующая ошибка:

> sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.followers - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables via secondary table 'followers'.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference from the secondary table to each of the parent and child tables.

Я гуглил ранее эту ошибку, но ничего не понял. Помогите пожалуйста. В SQLAlchemy полный ноль

Comment: Вот так пробовали https://stackoverflow.com/a/5652169/7753445 ?

Comment: @Alpensin Спасибо огромное. Заработало))